# Icon Not fit to Button Control in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my Asp project,..

I have used Icon file in Button. But those Icons not fit to Buttons. It half of the height only visible.

My Code is..

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnCoverPlus" runat="server"  
                    style="background-image: url('Images/plus.ico'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; width:32%; font-size:medium;"
                    Height="25px" onclick="btnCoverPlus_Click" /> <br />
```

How to fit the Icons in ASP buttons?.

Comment: Use a smaller icon, or use an `<img />` as the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious is to change the icon side, but you can also try to auto resize it with the style by adding :

```
background-size: 100% Auto;
```

or direct set the size

```
   background-size: 16px 16px;
```

*please note that only CSS 3 supports that.*

Answer (score 1):

try to increase button height by changing Height="25px property